# Spring 4.1 configuration for static content

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to modify Mkyong's Spring 3 MVC and JSON example (http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/) to work with Spring 4.1.x and allow reaching html files under webapp directory. For 4.0.x `<mvc:resources mapping="/*" location="/WEB-INF" />` with `servlet-mapping` did the trick, but it doesn't work in 4.1.x; `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCRest/index.html` gives 404 error. How can I configure it?

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringMVCRest</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SpringMVC Json Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>SpringMVCRest</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.controller" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:resources mapping="/*" location="/WEB-INF" /> 

</beans>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class JSONController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
Shop getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String name) {
    Shop shop = new Shop();
    shop.setName(name);
    shop.setStaffName(new String[] { "mkyong1", "mkyong2" });
    return shop;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML files are in the root of the webapp directory, they aren't under WEB-INF. So

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/*" location="/WEB-INF" />
```

should be

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/*" location="/" />
```